# my LSTM model accuracy is only around 0.5

Tags: python, lstm

I am trying to make a positive and negative classification with a review of Korean movies.
Data are pre-processed.
Preprocessed data is shared by Google drives.
It is configured by referring to example LSTM model.
When executed, the accuracy is only around 0.5.
Help me ......

this url is train_test_dataset.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rnf84idV9pj72Ammu5VQ2_rNyGZIa3pU/view?usp=sharing
train = 70000
test = about 33000

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding,Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM

max_features = 20000
maxlen = 300
batch_size = 32


import numpy as np
x_train = np.load('file_path')
y_train = np.load('file_path')
x_test = np.load('file_path')
y_test = np.load('file_path')


print('train_x shape:', train_x.shape)
print('test_x shape: ', test_x.shape)



print('model generate...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])



try:
    print('Train...')
    model.fit(train_x, train_y,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=1,
              validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
    score, acc = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y,
                                batch_size=batch_size)
    print('Test score:', score)
    print('Test accuracy:', acc)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: What sort of preprocessing did you use? Are you using word tokenization (converting words to integers)?

Comment: You probably will need to train for more than one epoch to see any improvement. Trying increasing the number of epochs and see if the training loss is decreasing. You also don't want to use the test set for the validation data.

Comment: I solved this problem.
The embedding caused trouble.